# Elasticsearch : Fuzzy query and filter results

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am very new to Elasticsearch and I am trying to create a search engine with Fuzzy query.

I can get results with Fuzzy search with this code :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "skill": {
        "query": "Project management",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results are very good but I would like to add the possibility to filter the results of the query on other parameters : For example I would like to keep only docs whose field "observatory" is one of those values : ["ROME", "ESCO"] (I need to supply those values as an array)

I tried something like this but I'm not sure why it's not working :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "skill": {
        "query": "Project management",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    },
    "filter" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "terms": {
              "observatory": ["ROME", "ESCO"],
              "minimum_should_match": 3
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

My question is : Is it possible to do search like this ? Fuzzy search and filter ?
And if yes : How to do it ?

My mapping is as follow :

```
{
  "skills": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "referentiel_id": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "observatory": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "language": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skill_id_ds_db": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skill_id_sm_db": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "skill": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "competence_id": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

EDIT : Here are some sample values from my `skill` index, for the output I need the same fields

```
{
  "_index": "skills",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "kUgpiXkB8y6qOrWRteCU",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "fields": {
    "observatory": [
      "ONET"
    ],
    "skill_id_sm_db": [
      "null"
    ],
    "skill_id_ds_db": [
      "1065629"
    ],
    "skill": [
      "Calibrate and test anesthesia equipment."
    ],
    "competence_id": [
      "null"
    ],
    "language": [
      "en"
    ],
    "referentiel_id": [
      "null"
    ],
    "type": [
      "hard"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index": "skills",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "PUgpiXkB8y6qOrWRrbKF",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "fields": {
    "observatory": [
      "ESCO"
    ],
    "skill_id_sm_db": [
      "null"
    ],
    "skill_id_ds_db": [
      "1049331"
    ],
    "skill": [
      "Types of engraving stone"
    ],
    "competence_id": [
      "null"
    ],
    "language": [
      "en"
    ],
    "referentiel_id": [
      "null"
    ],
    "type": [
      "hard"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_index": "skills",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "kkgpiXkB8y6qOrWRkASr",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "fields": {
    "observatory": [
      "null"
    ],
    "skill_id_sm_db": [
      "2254"
    ],
    "skill_id_ds_db": [
      "null"
    ],
    "skill": [
      "Fédérateur et sait innover pour mobiliser le management, les équipes et les salariés "
    ],
    "competence_id": [
      "null"
    ],
    "language": [
      "fr"
    ],
    "referentiel_id": [
      "8"
    ],
    "type": [
      "null"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`bool/must/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) clause

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "Vaccuuum",
  "observatory": "ABC"
}
{
  "name": "Vaccuum",
  "observatory": "ESCO"
}
{
  "name": "Vaccuum",
  "observatory": "ABC"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name": {
            "query": "Vacuumm",
            "fuzziness": "auto"
          }
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "observatory": [
            "rome",
            "esco"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67619660",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.7295573,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Vacuum",
          "observatory": "ROME"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67619660",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6253348,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Vaccuum",
          "observatory": "ESCO"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Agudolive where is the `name` field in your sample index data on which you are performing the match query ?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my code, I fixed it ;) There is no 'name' field, it is 'skill' field ! Sorry

Comment: @Agudolive no problem :-) Please go through the working example in my answer above, and let me know if this is what you expect to get ? Is this the same search result which you expect to get ?

Comment: I did try but it returned my no match :/

Comment: @Agudolive is the search result which I am getting above, is same which you expect to get ?

Comment: @Agudolive are you using `ROME` (with capital letters) in your search query ? You have to use it in lowercase since you have defined `"observatory"` field to be of `text` type. Please try with lower case and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Yes it's the same, except with all the fields but same spirit :) However I can't get any result with the query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232645/discussion-between-escoder-and-agudolive).